# Get rid of empty JSON values from map of interface{}

Tags: go

I have a struct in which I put all excess data into a `map[string]interface{}`.

If I unmarshal into the `Data` property with an empty variable, I don't want to keep it when marshalling. I basically need `interface{}` to have `json:",omitempty"`, How do I get that?

```
type Event struct {
    From string                 `json:"from"`
    Data map[string]interface{} `json:"data,omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: Please stop using `map[string]interface{}`. It defeats the entire point of the type system. Use appropriate types and you'll have an easier time of things. More code, but an easier time.

Comment: The reason that it´s a type `interface{}` is that it could be any objects.

Comment: It might help to know what you are trying to achieve by unmarshaling arbitrary json objects into interface{}. What's the next step?

Answer (score 0):

The `omitempty` is for encoding values, but not for decoding.

You cannot generate a complete empty map in Go. (Empty as in, it does not exists.) If your create a variable / value of a struct it always has its default value.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var m map[string]interface{}
    fmt.Printf("%v %d\n", m, len(m))
    // prints: map[] 0
    m = nil
    fmt.Printf("%v %d\n", m, len(m))
    // prints: map[] 0
}
```

Example: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YTN32d5kLm).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know if there's anything native that supports it. However until then, you can do it via reflection:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "should_exist": "foo",
        "should_omit": "",
    }
    for k, v := range m {
        if reflect.ValueOf(v).IsZero() {
            delete(m, k)
        }
    }
    data, _ := json.Marshal(m)
    fmt.Println(string(data)) // {"should_exist":"foo"}
}
```

Please note the performance hit this might cause in some use cases.